# Jquery Cookie show/hide menu via modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I am trying to setup 2 different nav menu and for the first time visitors (site wide) I want them to show a modal first where they will have to select (mandatory) which version should they choose then the corresponding nav will be shown on the page - but this has to be remembered via cookie and should expire within 30 days period.  Only one version of nav menu will be shown based on what they've clicked on the modal form.

Code Example:

```
<div id="menu-A">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="menu-B">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>


        <!-- modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Choose Your Setting - Split Nav</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-navA">Menu A</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-large btn-navB">Menu B</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer remove-top">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Settings</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have searched all over the site I forgot the OP of this code below:

```
if ($.cookie('pop') == null) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $.cookie('pop', '30');
}
```

I am still struggling as to how can I possibly pop that modal for the first time visitors and offer 2 choices whether Nav A or B then hit save.  Only one nav should be shown once they select an option  To my understanding jQuery cookie should at least save the users preferences until expires but I am a total noob when it comes to scripting & cookies :(

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.cookie('MenuChoice')) {
    //show menu based on saved choice
}
else {
    //show modal
}
```

After user has chosen save it:

```
$.cookie('MenuChoice', CHOICE)
```